# Matching Enum with Struct::default() value/ Error: expected tuple struct or tuple variant, found associated function `A::default`

Tags: rust

I'd like to match enums that have struct values. When I'm doing matching an enum, it seems I'm required to provide a value for the Enum field if it has one.
I'd like to set this value to A::default(), and reference the values of this default, but that gives me the error:  `` expected tuple struct or tuple variant, found associated function `A::default ``. How can I work around this? [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=09c30f484b73f691618b52b381646268)

```rust
use std::default::Default;

struct A {
    val_1: i32,
    val_2: i32,
    val_3: Vec<String>,
}

impl Default for A {
    fn default() -> A {
        A {
            val_1: 0,
            val_2: 0,
            val_3: vec!["Hello".to_string()],
        }
    }
}

struct B {
    val_1: i32,
    val_2: i32,
    val_3: A,
}

impl Default for B {
    fn default() -> B {
        B {
            val_1: 0,
            val_2: 0,
            val_3: A::default(),
        }
    }
}

enum Ops {
    OpA { config: A },
    OpB { config: B },
}

struct Mast {
    pub OpType: Ops,
}
fn main() {
    let myop = Mast {
        OpType: Ops::OpA {
            config: A::default(),
        },
    };

    match myop.OpType {
        Ops::OpA{ config: A::default() } => {
            println!("{}", "got OpA"),
            println!("{}", A::default().val_1),

        }//<--'expected tuple struct or tuple variant, found associated function `A::default`'
        Ops::OpB{ config: B::default() } => println!("{}", "got OpB"),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't care about the struct field value, so use `..` to ignore the value:

```rust
match myop.OpType {
    Ops::OpA {..} => println!("{}", "got OpA"),
    Ops::OpB {..} => println!("{}", "got OpA"),
}
```

If you want to extract the `config` field into a variable, let's say `foo`, then you can do this:

```rust
match myop.OpType {
    Ops::OpA {config: foo} => println!("OpA: {}", foo),
    Ops::OpB {config: foo} => println!("OpB: {}", foo),
}
```

This is also why your old code doesn't work: because pattern matching extracts patterns into variables, and it does not check values for equality.

If you want to mutate it, then match it by `ref`:

```rust
match myop.OpType {
    Ops::OpA {config: ref mut foo} => *foo = A::default(),
    Ops::OpB {config: ref mut foo} => *foo = B::default(),
}
```

This will require `myop` to be `mut` as well. There's also a shorthand, `{config}`, which will expand to `{config: config}`:

```rust
match myop.OpType {
    Ops::OpA {ref mut config} => *config = A::default(),
    Ops::OpB {ref mut config} => *config = B::default(),
}
```

See also:

- [*The Rust Language: Pattern Syntax*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#ignoring-values-in-a-pattern)
- [*The Rust Reference: Patterns*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html)